# How can I change the font face in Latex to be Times New Roman, 11 points, line spacing 16 points?

Tags: fonts

I used Latex with this formate

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lscape}
```

How can I change the font face in Latex to be Times New Roman, 11 points, line spacing 16 points?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `amssymb` package, there's really no need, or justification, for loading the deprecated `latexsym` package. And, the `hyperref` package should be loaded last, not first.

Comment: You'll need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the `fontspec` package for that and the font installed on your machine. There should be plenty resources about using a system font in LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico --- don't forget `epsfig`!

Comment: @IanThompson - Do you want to do the honors, i.e., point out that there can’t be a purpose in loading `epsfig` If the OP’s TeX distribution is less than ca 12 years old? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it absolutely has to be Times New Roman, as opposed to some Times Roman clone, you'll have to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Most (virtually all?) operating systems feature Times New Roman as a system font, and both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX provide access to system fonts. As pdfLaTeX doesn't offer direct access to system fonts, you'll have to make do with a (high-quality!) clone of Times Roman if you work with pdfLaTeX.

The code shown at the bottom of this answer should get you started with both LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX.

Here's the output produced by LuaLaTeX (MacTeX 2017, MacOSX 10.13.2 "High Sierra"):

[image]

And here's the output produced by pdfLaTeX on the same system.

[image]

I'd say that only *real* font experts will readily detect differences between Times New Roman (shown in the upper screenshot) and Times Roman (shown in the lower screenshot.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum,microtype}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % choose page parameters suitably
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
  \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\else % assume pdfLaTeX
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone
\fi

\linespread{1.17647} % = 16/13.6. Why 13.6? Because
    %% 13.6 is the "standard" value of baselineskip 
    %% for Times Roman set at 11 pt.

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\em\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say `\linespread{1.17647}` rather than calling `\fontsize`; this ensures proportionally enlarged line spacing also in other contexts; also, `\normalsize` would cancel the change in the baseline skip. Unfortunately font *nonexperts* will look in the properties of the PDF file.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this suggestion! Using `\linespread` is indeed far more general -- and, as you observe, it "survives" any `\normalsize` calls.

Comment: Do you mean 'most Windows operating systems'? Linux certainly does not and OS X didn't when I last used it (which was a while ago). OS X provided Times. Linux provides neither --- unless you're using some niche commercial or illegal distribution, they can't. OS X often has TNR installed because MS Office is often installed, but it isn't supplied by the OS.